# ios cordova - Scrolling issue when using vertical and horizontal scrolling

Tags: html, ios, css, cordova, safari

I'm building a Cordova based app and it's been going well so far but I've got a scrolling issue on iOS.

Basically, I have a table inside a div that scrolls horizontally and I have the rest of the page, made up of a parent div that should scroll vertically - and it all works unless you try scrolling the main page while touching the table on ios.

```
<div class="example_container" style="height:220px;width:200px;">
    <div class="example_slide" id="example_slide_1" style="text-align:center;height:100%;overflow:auto;">
        <div style="width:80%;margin:auto;overflow-x:scroll;">
            <table>{table content}</table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6m0yp92o/11/embedded/result/) (which is a bit fiddly to use since I can't stop the body from scrolling) essentially if you try scrolling the box while touching the table on ios, you can't but if you touch around the line under the table, the box scrolls normally.

I think it's because it's trying to scroll the body or html but I've tried preventing them from scrolling with position:fixed; and overflow:hidden; with the same results.

This works as expected on android and when emulating on chrome in windows but does not work in safari on ios or in my cordova app - if anyone could tell me why, that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this in css `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;`  to make the scrolling work in Safari (ios).